# Sharepoint column - Calculate number of hours to next day 11AM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow, power-automate, sharepoint-list-filter

In share point lists, How to find if the record was created between 10 AM yesterday to 11 AM today ?

Need this for List->View ->Filter and also to check in Power automate to see if the record is eligible for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here're steps:

1.Create a calculated column by using below formula first.

```
=TEXT(Created-DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),DAY(Created)),"hh:mm")
```

2.Create two views.One view filter 10 AM to 24 PM yesterday,another 0 PM to 11 AM today.

First view:

[image]

Second view:

[image]

Comment: Why do we need two views ? If there are 2 view how could it be combined so that the current view is a combined one..object is to show records that was created between 10 AM yesterday to 11 AM today. This should happen daily and we cannot hard code the date in condition